# Hashtable returns null in JAVA

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm trying to input a few key value pairs into a hashtable, encode the data, then decode in in a separate android activity. However, the Hashtable returns null, when I try to get the values.

First, I'm passing a hex string as an input:

```
String result="000700016D0009393837363"+
              "7363636360001620002422B"+
              "00016C000553696E6768000"+
              "17300044D616C6500016600"+
              "05526168756C00017020A";
```

Following which, I'm decoding the string as follows-

```
System.out.println("hijk...."+Util.hex2ByteArray(result)+"aa "+Util.hex2ByteArray(result).length);

Hashtable<String , String> htParams = new MobileEncoderDecoder().decode(Util.hex2ByteArray(result));

System.out.println(htParams);
System.out.println("lmno...");
```

Where `Util.hex2ByteArray(result)` uses a class that converts the given hex string to a byte array. The problem's not in in converting from hex to Byte Array, as I've printed the value of the Byte Array and it is correct.

`MobileEncoderDecoder()` is a class that has the `decode()` method, described as follows-

```
public Hashtable decode(byte[] byData) 
{
    try
    {
        Hashtable htParams = new Hashtable();
        if(byData == null || byData.length == 0)
            return null;
        DataInputStream oStream = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byData));
        int iTotalParameters = oStream.readShort();

        for(int i=0; i < iTotalParameters; i++)
        {
            byte[] byParam = new byte[oStream.readShort()];
            oStream.read(byParam);

            int iValueLen = oStream.readShort();
            byte[] byValue = null;

            if(iValueLen > 0)
            {
                byValue = new byte[iValueLen];
                oStream.read(byValue);
            }

            if(byValue != null)

                htParams.put(new String(byParam), new String(byValue));
        }

        return htParams;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem's not in the input string, the conversion from hex to byte array. The run time error occurs on the line where I'm decoding the byte array. i.e.

Hashtable htParams = new MobileEncoderDecoder().decode(Util.hex2ByteArray(result));

How do I fix it?

EDIT- Here's my Log

```
06-18 12:53:29.182: D/OpenGLRenderer(15346): Enabling debug mode 0
06-18 12:53:30.412: I/AndroidRuntime(15346): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
06-18 12:53:35.109: I/Adreno-EGL(15627): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:385>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
06-18 12:53:35.109: I/Adreno-EGL(15627): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.01
06-18 12:53:35.109: I/Adreno-EGL(15627): Build Date: 12/11/13 Wed
06-18 12:53:35.109: I/Adreno-EGL(15627): Local Branch: 8226workspace
06-18 12:53:35.109: I/Adreno-EGL(15627): Remote Branch: 
06-18 12:53:35.109: I/Adreno-EGL(15627): Local Patches: 
06-18 12:53:35.109: I/Adreno-EGL(15627): Reconstruct Branch: 
06-18 12:53:35.136: D/OpenGLRenderer(15627): Enabling debug mode 0
06-18 12:53:36.063: I/System.out(15627): 12345
06-18 12:53:37.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15627): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-18 12:53:42.566: I/System.out(15627): abcdef....
06-18 12:53:42.569: I/System.out(15627): hijk....[B@41ff7730aa56
06-18 12:53:42.572: I/System.out(15627): ****Total Parameters : 7
06-18 12:53:42.573: W/System.err(15627): java.io.EOFException
06-18 12:53:42.580: W/System.err(15627):    at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
06-18 12:53:42.580: W/System.err(15627):    at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(DataInputStream.java:152)
06-18 12:53:42.580: W/System.err(15627):    at com.example.androscan.MobileEncoderDecoder.decode(MobileEncoderDecoder.java:37)
06-18 12:53:42.580: W/System.err(15627):    at com.example.androscan.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:131)
06-18 12:53:42.580: W/System.err(15627):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
06-18 12:53:42.580: W/System.err(15627):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
06-18 12:53:42.581: W/System.err(15627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
06-18 12:53:42.581: W/System.err(15627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
06-18 12:53:42.581: W/System.err(15627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-18 12:53:42.581: W/System.err(15627):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
06-18 12:53:42.581: W/System.err(15627):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-18 12:53:42.581: W/System.err(15627):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-18 12:53:42.581: W/System.err(15627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
06-18 12:53:42.582: W/System.err(15627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 12:53:42.582: W/System.err(15627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-18 12:53:42.582: W/System.err(15627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-18 12:53:42.583: W/System.err(15627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-18 12:53:42.584: W/System.err(15627):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 12:53:42.584: I/System.out(15627): null
06-18 12:53:42.584: I/System.out(15627): lmno...
06-18 12:53:42.584: D/AndroidRuntime(15627): Shutting down VM
06-18 12:53:42.584: W/dalvikvm(15627): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416e4d40)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627): Process: com.example.androscan, PID: 15627
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androscan/com.example.androscan.MainActivity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at com.example.androscan.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:134)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
06-18 12:53:42.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15627):    ... 11 more
06-18 12:53:44.447: I/Process(15627): Sending signal. PID: 15627 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Start by checking what is the return value from: `Util.hex2ByteArray(result)` (probably either `null` or an empty byte array).

Comment: No, as I said, I've checked the value it returns. It gives a byte array. To be precise, it gives [B@42009068

Comment: @Deathstroke - have you checked the length of the array???

Comment: 1. What is null? The hashtable or hashtable.get(somekey)?
2. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Show us the stacktrace for the runtime error.

Comment: @RonK, that is the condition given in case the byte array is null. But it neither is null, nor is its length 0.

Comment: @Deathstroke - what about an exception? Also causes null

Comment: @RonK, No, I added a print line in the exception to see if it prints. It doesn't print in the console, which means the exception is not being invoked.

Comment: @StephenC, please see my updated question for the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

This way of reading a byte-array is very hacky and error-prone, but if you insist on doing it the least you should do is check that there are enough bytes to read before any `read()` you're executing.

Since you're only reading `short` (2-bytes) you should check that there are at least two bytes in the stream before every read:

```
public static Hashtable decode(byte[] byData) throws Exception
{        
    try
    {
        Hashtable htParams = new Hashtable();
        if(byData == null || byData.length == 0)
            return null;
        DataInputStream oStream = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byData));
        int iTotalParameters = oStream.readShort();

        for(int i=0; i < iTotalParameters; i++)
        {
            if(oStream.available() < 2)
                break;
            int len = oStream.readShort();
            byte[] byParam = new byte[len];
            if(oStream.available() <2)
                break;
            oStream.read(byParam);
            if(oStream.available() <2)
                break;
            int iValueLen = oStream.readShort();
            byte[] byValue = null;

            if(iValueLen > 0)
            {
                byValue = new byte[iValueLen];
                if(oStream.available() < 2)
                    break;
                oStream.read(byValue);
            }

            if(byValue != null)

                htParams.put(new String(byParam), new String(byValue));
        }

        return htParams;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The output that I'm getting is:

```
i = b; val: B+
i = m; val: 987676666
i = l; val: Singh
i = s; val: Male
i = f; val: Rahul
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case - from the exception it looks like he had an EOF from reading the bytearray

Comment: Hmmmm...will using int instead of short fix the error?

Comment: @Deathstroke not with the `result` string you provided. Where did you get that string and why are you trying to read it as Hex to byte-array ?

Comment: This string contains various parameters like Name, Age, Phone Number and an image. The input string is correct. I'm reading it as Hex to Byte-Array, because the decode() function takes in a byte array as the argument.

Comment: @alfasin. I figured out the error. Turns out, the key value pair for the image parameter was messing things up. Apart from the above parameters, i.e. Name Blood Group, Sex, etc..I was also passing an image. I printed out the oStream.readShort() values for all keys. It gave the length of all the values for eack key. i.e. 2 for 'B+', 9 for '987676666' and so on. For the image, it gave 8354. When I used an image of less than 1KB, the value of its oStream.readShort() gave 1238 and it worked perfectly.